# Determining the SVG viewport in global/root coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg

The content actually visible inside an SVG element depends on its aspect ratio, its [`viewBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) value, and its [`preserveAspectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) value.

For example, the same SVG element size with the same `viewBox` value (dotted red below) can have different viewports (shown in blue below) depending on the `preserveAspectRatio`:

[image: pictoral examples of varying preserveAspectRatio settings and the resulting viewboxes]

- Chrome has a `viewport` property, but in my uses it's always an empty (all 0-valued) SVGRect. Firefox does not implement this property.
- The `svg.getBBox()` method returns the value of the `viewBox`, not the actual visible viewport content.

Given a reference to a SVG element, how can I most easily determine the visible content (the viewport), expressed in the user coordinates at the root of the SVG (the same coordinates as the `viewBox`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function that works for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. See the test page here:

#### Test Page: http://phrogz.net/SVG/CalculateSVGViewport.html

```js
// Given an <svg> element, returns an object with the visible bounds
// expressed in local viewBox units, e.g.
// { x:-50, y:-50, width:100, height:100 }
function calculateViewport(svg){ // http://phrogz.net/JS/_ReuseLicense.txt
  var style    = getComputedStyle(svg),
      owidth   = parseInt(style.width,10),
      oheight  = parseInt(style.height,10),
      aspect   = svg.preserveAspectRatio.baseVal,
      viewBox  = svg.viewBox.baseVal,
      width    = viewBox && viewBox.width  || owidth,
      height   = viewBox && viewBox.height || oheight,
      x        = viewBox ? viewBox.x : 0,
      y        = viewBox ? viewBox.y : 0;
  if (!width || !height || !owidth || !oheight) return;
  if (aspect.align==aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_NONE || !viewBox || !viewBox.height){
    return {x:x,y:y,width:width,height:height};
  }else{
    var inRatio  = viewBox.width / viewBox.height,
        outRatio = owidth / oheight;
    var meetFlag = aspect.meetOrSlice != aspect.SVG_MEETORSLICE_SLICE;
    var fillAxis = outRatio>inRatio ? (meetFlag?'y':'x') : (meetFlag?'x':'y');
    if (fillAxis=='x'){
      height = width/outRatio;
      var diff = viewBox.height - height;
      switch (aspect.align){
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_UNKNOWN: 
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMINYMID:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMIDYMID:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMAXYMID:
          y += diff/2;
        break;
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMINYMAX:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMIDYMAX:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMAXYMAX:
          y += diff;
        break;
      }
    }
    else{
      width = height*outRatio;
      var diff = viewBox.width - width;
      switch (aspect.align){
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_UNKNOWN: 
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMIDYMIN:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMIDYMID:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMIDYMAX:
          x += diff/2;
        break;
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMAXYMID:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMAXYMIN:
        case aspect.SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMAXYMAX:
          x += diff;
        break;
      }
    }
    return {x:x,y:y,width:width,height:height};
  }
}
```

Comment: It's 2021 now, do you know if new APIs have been developped to avoid reimplementing this in the page javascript ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @jonenst I just needed this again, and my searching shows no other answer so far. (I'd even forgotten I'd written this!)